# Regex to select string only between specific strings, uninclusive

Tags: regex, html-parsing

Can someone help - need a regular expression that will select any and all STRING that occur ONLY between STRINGA and STRINGB, regardless of line break.  I've tried researching this without success.  Other "between two strings" queries on here haven't been helpful.

Specifically, I need to select ONLY  tags (including the lt gt symbols) ONLY between h3 tags.

```
<p>  asdf <strong> ghkjk 
   <strong> qwer </p>
<h3> asdf **<strong>** gh
   kjk **<strong>** qwer </h3>
```

I can make it select ONLY all  tags; and I can make it select the full sequence of the <h3> and </h3> tags.  But I can't see how to combine those two conditions.  (btw, [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) is a great tool!)
Thanks.

Comment: What language/tool do you use?

Comment: What operating system do you use? Matching strings across newlines can be tricky depending on the tools you have available.

Comment: i have created a demo check this link `https://regex101.com/r/xW7vL3/1` and http://regexr.com/3b7je on regexr.com

Comment: You should definitely read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454).

Comment: You can use `<h3>[\s\S]*?</h3>`. You might neeed to escape the forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not easy to work with when it comes to regex and it can almost always fail in specific (and rare) cases. However, extracting info from tags is, for the most part, possible. Extracting info from a table (which then can have another table inside of it) is where regex starts to crumble.

I came up with `(?<=\<[hH]3\>)(.|\s)*?(?=\<\/[hH]3\>)`, which solves the simple situation (`<h3>info</h3>`)

https://regex101.com/r/qK6uT4/1

Note that this won't work like it is in javascript due to a positive lookbehind. The idea is that it checks if there's a h3 tag before and a /h3 tag after with [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

`(.|\s)*?` means that any symbol and any space including newlines occur the minimum amount of times (so you don't get symbols between one `<h3>` tag and the `</h3>` of another one.

To deal with situations like `<h3 class="someclass">`, if they are relevant, the previous regex fails.

`(?:\<[hH]3(?:\s.*?)?\>)((.|\s)*?)(?=\<\/[hH]3\>)`

can be used and capture groups ($1) would be your results.

https://regex101.com/r/qK6uT4/3

Answer (score 0):

regex for detecting if a tablet comes with 4G/3G/LTE

```
var txt1 = document.querySelector('.product-title').textContent.trim();
var ans;   

if(txt1.match(/\b4G\b/gi) || txt1.match(/\bLTE\b/gi) || txt1.match(/\b3G\b/gi) ||txt1.match(/ Cellular/gi)||txt1.match(/ Cell /gi) || txt1.match(/ 4G /g)  || txt1.match(/ LTE /g) || txt1.match(/ 3G /g) || txt1.match(/\b4G\b,/g)|| txt1.match(/\b3G\b,/g))  
{
ans= '1';
} 
else 
{
ans= '0';
}
```